# how to ng-model use in table row , and change data on runtime

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to use `ng-model` with database textbox, anyone know, I want change value on runtime, I want enter dates on runtime but `ng-model` show same value

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in showAddedAssets  ">           
 <td >  <md-datepicker  id="startmd"name="plainnedstartdate" ng-change="createCampaign.changedate(row)"  ng-model="createCampaign.assets_planned_start_date" required></md-datepicker></td>
 <td  >  <md-datepicker name="plainnedenddate"  ng-change="createCampaign.changedate(row)" ng-model="createCampaign.assets_planned_end_date" required></md-datepicker></td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS FILE**

```
changedate(assetitem)
 {
   assetitem.assets_planned_start_date = this.assets_planned_start_date ;
   assetitem.assets_planned_end_date  = this.assets_planned_end_date;
 }
```

Comment: Is that JS in a controller?

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. You should provide a better explanation of what you are trying to do. Your `ng-model` is inherited by all `row` elements of the array, so they will all have the same model, try to use `ng-model="row"` instead. Are you using _Controller as_ syntax? If so, then you need `createcampaign.showAddedAssets`